Cant see open applications via RDP
I'm using RDP to log into my Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS machine from my windows 11 machine over the local network. I successfully log in (having also enabled the remote login option), but when I open apps such as files or settings, the icon appears on the left hand side, but I can't see the actual application, just the desktop.
Firefox, app center, and the terminal work.  Perhaps some sort of security setting needs enabling?!
If I use destkop sharing + remote control, I am able to see open applications, so this is only affecting remote login.
I'm using the latest nvidia tested driver 550.

I resolved by updating to Ubuntu 24.10, not sure why that worked, but it worked.

Ok, this is not a good answer, because the 24.10 version is not stable enough in various other applications such as anaconda.
I've had to switch back to 24.04.2, and now I'm back facing this issue.  So if anyone knows the resolution that would be great.
